# Не выполняется CURL-запрос

Tags: php, telegram-bot, curl

Мне нужно выполнять запрос:

[https://api.telegram.org/bot1933554209:AAG_wpAycxK5F1cj-NEH_ZV4NM3CCkEAnHI/sendMessage?chat_id=919680226&text=Сообщение](https://api.telegram.org/bot1933554209:AAG_wpAycxK5F1cj-NEH_ZV4NM3CCkEAnHI/sendMessage?chat_id=919680226&text=%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)

Данный запрос должен отправлять сообщение от имени бота в телеграмме.
Токен бота и айди пользователя указаны верно.
Если вручную данный запрос выполнить в адресной строке - все работает, однако, при попытке выполнить данный запрос нижеприведенным способом используя PHP - ничего не происходит.
Не понимаю, в чём проблем. Пробовал осуществить данный запрос разными способами, в том числе с помощью file_get_contents, однако, ни один способ не смог выполнить.

```
<?php
define('TELEGRAM_TOKEN', '1933554209:AAG_wpAycxK5F1cj-NEH_ZV4NM3CCkEAnHI');
define('TELEGRAM_CHATID', '919680226');
$message = 'Сообщение';
$ch = curl_init('https://api.telegram.org/bot'.TELEGRAM_TOKEN.'/sendMessage?chat_id='.TELEGRAM_CHATID.'&text='.$message);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Comment: смотреть ответ `curl_exec` религия не позволяет?

Comment: echo curl_exec($ch); //ничего не выводит

Comment: и не должен. Для таких целей есть `var_dump`

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, а почему запрос не выполняется?

Comment: [Выполняется](https://paiza.io/projects/JOLgv99HLjz-Ovwdgghl5w) без проблем. У вас вообще расширение curl включено?